# API Doesn't Support IPv6, App Rejected. What Can I Do?

Tags: swift, xcode, api, appstore-approval

I've created an app and tried to publish to the App Store only to be rejected as the app crashes on launch when using an IPv6 only network.

I used IPv6-test.com and tested the demo API URL to find that the API doesn't support IPv6 yet. Is there a way I can get around this issue without using a different API?

If it could help I have the capabilities to host my own server with IPv6 support.

Comment: Are you talking about the Alamofire Swift library?

Comment: @7vikram7 I'm using the Alamofire library but the issue is the IPv6 support, I tagged Alamofire too just in case there was a way to resolve it by using it

Comment: Latest version of Alamorfire (rather 3.4.1+) is IVP6 compliant

Comment: @7vikram7 I'm using the latest Alamofire, the problem is that the API server doesn't support IPv6

Answer (score 1):

For an API server to be compatible with IPV6, you will need to just deploy it on a web server which is IPv6 enabled.

If its a Third party API on a Third party web server, I think there is not much you can do apart from writing and requesting to them  to enable IPV6.

If its your own Web server, you can ask your hosting provider for an IPv6 address and check if they can provide you with IPv6 connectivity.